# How does one consolidate version management in Ivy, like parent-pom <dependencyManagement> in Maven?

Tags: ant, maven, ivy, dependency-management

We have many projects that need to use common version numbers.
What is best practice for doing this with Ant/Ivy?  Do you just inherit a wad of properties from Ant that have the version numbers in them, or is there a more formal mechanism a la Maven?

Comment: Looks like the new <extends> in ivy.xml gets at some of this.  See [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-742), [doc](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/extends.html).  Not sure on best use yet, though.

Answer (score 2):

As you've pointed out I think this is the problem which the new [extends](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/extends.html) functionality has been designed to solve.

To be completely honest I'm not a fan of parent-child modules in Maven.... However, just like you sometimes I want to nail lots of my modules to a common version of Spring.

The solution I used was to have a set of [properties defined in my shared ivysettings](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/property.html) file. This keeps my ivy specific properties separate from my ANT build properties.