# IVY Extends Loses Dependency Declaration

Tags: dependencies, ivy, extends

I recently updated my project structure to use IVY:Extends functionality where I declared a parent (common-ivy.xml) and extend that in all the projects (I have around 120 projects using this). I achieve that by using the technique in this thread [IVY Extends via ivy:resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144464/ivy-extends-via-ivyresolve) .

Now the problem is that after adopting to this structure I have lost the dependency between the projects which is essential and its now breaking everything. For example see below;

**common-ivy.xml**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://repository.temenosgroup.com/xsl/version-doc.xsl"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
    <info organisation="xyz" branch="15" module="CommonDependency" revision="1.0.0" />
    <configurations defaultconfmapping="test->test(*);compile->compile(*)">
        <conf name="test" description="Test Time dependencies"/>
        <conf name="compile" description="Compile Time dependencies"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.8.2" conf="compile,test"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

**ProjectZ ivy.xml** extends common but does not define any additional dependency

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://repository.temenosgroup.com/xsl/version-doc.xsl"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
    <info module="ProjectZ" >
        <extends extendType="all"
                 organisation="xyz"
                 module="CommonDependency"
                 revision="1.0.0"
                 location="../parent/common-ivy.xml" />
    </info>
    <dependencies />
</ivy-module>
```

**ProjectA ivy.xml** extends common as well as define its dependency on ProjectZ

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://repository.temenosgroup.com/xsl/version-doc.xsl"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
    <info module="ProjectA" >
        <extends extendType="all"
                 organisation="xyz"
                 module="CommonDependency"
                 revision="1.0.0"
                 location="../parent/common-ivy.xml" />
    </info>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="xyz" name="ProjectZ" branch="15" rev="latest-dev" conf="compile,test"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

When I am passing this list to `ivy:buildlist` its returning following order;

```
ProjectA, ProjectZ
```

which is **INCORRECT** it should have returned;

```
ProjectZ, ProjectA
```

I am using IVY 2.3.0. Is it a bug in IVY or am I missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't your extends declaration include branch="15" to properly reference the common-ivy.xml ?

Comment: extends does not support `branch` attribute it would be used directly from common-ivy.xml in each project. The problem is in Dependencies where ProjectA declares its dependency on ProjectZ but IVY is not able to recognize it

Answer (score 1):

OK I had to debug the IVY :( to resolve this issue and found out that the `rev` of the dependency along with the common-ivy.xml was causing the problem. While debugging I found two solutions;

**1) Use rev="+" in dependency definition and let IVY resolve whatever is available**

**2) Remove `revision="1.0.0"` from common-ivy.xml as it is inherited because of `extends` and hence IVY fails to match latest-dev==1.0.0, once removed from common-ivy.xml my project becomes working@HostName which is correctly resolved by IVY**

I chose option 2 as it requires changes in a single file and attribute is not in use in my work space anyway.